# Prospective student’s first email to a potential advisor?

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-process, masters, advisor, email

I am applying for an MSc program and I need to find an advisor prior to sending in my application. I have heard conflicting advise regarding what to put in my first email. I would like some opinion on this matter.

Do I include my CV in the first email?

Do I mention my GPA?

Do I straight-up ask them if they are accepting students? Or, do I first attempt to establish a relationship?